# How do you include a goto label in a command line parameters for cmd.exe ?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Does anyone know how can you include goto label in the command string passed to cmd.exe ?

Something like this:

```
cmd.exe /c ":retry & copy /y new_file.exe file.exe & if [%errorlevel%]==[1] goto :retry"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accomplish your logic by putting your command in an infinite loop, and have it EXIT upon success. I'm not sure I recommend this, since an error could result in a truly infinite loop.

```
cmd.exe /c "for /l %N in () do @copy /y new_file.exe file.exe && exit"
```

I suppose you could add a counter that EXITs after N number of failed attempts. Here is an example that exits immediately upon success, and also exits if it fails 3 times.

```
cmd.exe /c "for /l %N in () do @copy /y new_file.exe file.exe && exit || >nul 2>&1 set /a 1/((failCnt+=1)%3) || exit"
```

Comment: EDIT - Simplified infinite loop syntax. Fixed %N for command line context. Added example of maximum allowed failures.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, you can't use goto or call with a label on the cmd line.
Labels work only inside batch files.

But if your line is itself in a batch file, you could restart your batch file with a parameter.

mybatch.bat

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="intern" goto %2

echo First start
cmd.exe /c myBatch.bat intern :myLabel
echo after
exit /b

:myLabel
echo second start
exit /b
```

Comment: I know you can use labels in batch files. I was wondering though, if you can use jumps in a command string passed to cmd.exe. I call cmd.exe from another language and I was avoiding creating the batch file, but it looks like there is no escape.